# Парсинг страниц

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отпарсить правильно данную [страничку](http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620), мне нужны ссылки на картинки, использую `simple_html_dom`, но почему-то возвращает мне одни иероглифы, уже пробовал любые функции для смены кодировки - ничего не помогает!

Comment: Данные которые вы птаитесь получить намеренно зашифрованы программистами! На форуме расшифровками никто заниматься не будет!

Comment: Ясно спасибо

Comment: > намеренно зашифрованы программистами

Ага, но при этом в браузере нет никаких кракозябр. Как так могло получиться?

Comment: вам нужны ссылки на изображения только этой страницы? и, если да, на все или на какую-то определенную их часть?

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите внимательно как отдаётся эта страница:

```
wget -S "http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620"
--15:27:29--  http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620
           => `inf.pl@1272404620'
Resolving devilscity.combats.com... done.
Connecting to devilscity.combats.com[194.126.211.23]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
 1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 2 Server: nginx
 3 Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2012 11:27:29 GMT
 4 Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
 5 Content-Length: 4103
 6 Connection: keep-alive
 7 Content-Encoding: gzip
 8 Expires: 0
 9 Pragma: no-cache
10 Cache-control: no-cache
```

Видите строчку номер 7? Это значит, что отдаётся страница, ужатая gzip. И сначала нужно её разжать:

```
$page = gzdecode((file_get_contents('http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Похоже что сервер отдаёт контент только в сжатом виде (с помощью gzip). Вам нужно установить флаг для curl, сделать принудительное использование gzip. Или ещё какими методами, как это сделать конкретно в PHP -- ХЗ.

Из шелла получить вашу страничку в текстовом виде можно к примеру так:

```
curl 'http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620' --compressed
```

Comment: вот похоже по-теме: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310650/

Comment: AlexWindHope мне надо вставлять ссылку в текстовое поле,структура страниц одна и та же просто айди игроков разные будут,мне надо считывать значки возле ника,больше мне ничего не надо,просто если у меня  в базе будет около 500 персонажей вручную копировать все ссылки картинок это просто нереально!

Comment: Покопался  в гугле и нашел очень хороший способ! в итоге все получилось,осталось только выбрать нужные ссылки!

$ch = curl_init('http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620');
  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    ));
    
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo gzinflate(substr($res, 10));

Comment: В данном случае gzip отдаётся всегда, поэтому пляски с курлом не нужны вообще. А для того, чтобы подобный метод был универсальным, надо ещё проверять что отдалось. Потому как не факт, что если ты попросил gzip, то сервер его отдаст и нужно будет что-то распаковывать.

Comment: Ну так меня интересует только эта страница,а сервер всегда отдает ее в гзипе!

Comment: Я о том и говорю: в данном случае ни курл, ни дополнительные HTTP-заголовки не нужны в принципе, всё укладывается в в одну строчку с file_get_contents/gzdecode.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал `simple_html_dom` почему то не получается

```
$url = 'http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1253518743';
$result = file_get_html($url);

$res_deсoded = gzinflate(substr($result,10));

echo $res_deсoded;
```

Comment: И ведь 2 раза написали как нужно...Но раз хочется изобрести свой велосипед с квадратными колёсами - объясните что ваш код делает, построчно, и как именно он должен работать.

Comment: Ну я только начинаю осваивать парсинг читаю все что связано с этим,пробую! Не судите строго. Работая с file_get_contents данные обрабатывать прийдется регулярными выражениями,в simple_html_dom все намного проще поэтому и решил попробовать,буду очень благодарен если вы подскажите еще какие то способы манипулации с содержимым,не используя рег. выражения!

Comment: Для того, чтобы воспользоваться simple_html_dom, надо сначала получить контент. В вашем случае - сначала получить, потом распаковать, потом уже создавать структуру. Например:
       
    $data = gzdecode((file_get_contents($url));
    $dom_html = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom_html->load($data); 
    /* ... */

Что, в какой последовательности и зачем делает ваш код - непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное,очень помогли,только функция gzdecode не работает,получается только с gzinflate